# Folland theorem 2.42 b

Tags: real-analysis

I don't understand why in the proof of b, the equality $\int (f\circ \tau_a)d\mu=\int d\mu$ reduces to the equality $m(\tau_{-a}(E))=m(E)$ when $f=\chi E$?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f = \chi_E$ then $f\circ \tau_a = \chi_{\tau_{-a}(E)}$. Indeed, $f\circ \tau_a(x) = 1$ precisely when $\tau_a(x)\in E$  or, equivalently, $x+a\in E \iff x\in \tau_{-a}(E)$.
Ergo,
$$
\int f\mathrm{d}\mu = m(E)
\quad\text{and}\quad
\int f\circ \tau_a = m\left(\tau_{-a}(E)\right)
$$